# My manuscript gets "with Editor" then "Editor invited", What is the main reasons for this?

Tags: publications

My manuscript status shows "With Editor" after initial submission. Then, (after two days) it takes "Editor invited". So, once, it with Editor, It should take the next step. However, it backs again to the first step. I really do not understand why it takes this two different status in a very short time?  What would this indicate? That is, my paper at the first time finds an editor, then they look for an editor to my paper?!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does the typical workflow of a journal look like?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/55665/what-does-the-typical-workflow-of-a-journal-look-like)

Comment: Welcome to Academia.SE! Your question already has an answer [here](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/55665/what-does-the-typical-workflow-of-a-journal-look-like), so it will be closed soon. Thank you!

Comment: @TheDoctor I am not asking for the process of the journal, I just wonder why my paper was with Editor then Editor invited?

Comment: @TheDoctor: I don’t see how this case is covered by the proposed duplicate.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft It is impossible to answer exactly what the specific status of a journal means and why someone in the staff changed it. For example, I have a paper that changed status in the following order in the same day: *Quality Check started-> Editor Assigned -> Quality Check started*. Should it be a valid question for Academia.SE why that happened? Some status changes are only for the staff, not for authors. The best answer we have is about the general and typical workflow of a journal.

Comment: However, we are able to edit the answer for that question and introduce the possibility of this situation happening. This status change may appear when the initial editor is not available anymore.

Comment: @TheDoctor: We may not know what happened exactly, but we may make an educated guess. Worst thing that can happen is that the question remains unanswered. — *we are able to edit the answer for that question and introduce the possibility of this situation happening* – the canonical question exists to cover a regular workflow, i.e., the basics. It was created to avoid hundreds of redundant questions on this. It cannot, needs not, and should not cover every eventuality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It could be that someone pressed the wrong button.

Or the editor wasn't able to review after they initially took in on and put it out for another to pick up (probably good practice, rather than it sitting in someone's in-tray unread).

If you think it's a big deal, then contact the journal. But maybe give it a couple of weeks first.